# Use Linkedin API to retrieve my profile info

Tags: javascript, python, api, linkedin-api, web-development-server

I am developing my personal website and I want to retrieve my profile info on my Linkedin account by using the Linkedin API, so whenever I update on Linkedin, my personal website will be updated automatically as well. But this service needs to gain the OAUth2 token by logging in. How I can login (or gain OAuth2 token) from code-behind with my username and password, instead of manually login every-time? Prefer using JavaScript (client-side) or Python (server-side)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use your username and password to obtain an Authentication key with LinkedIn.  After authenticating yourself, you should be able to work with the API.

You can find information on how to do this [here (link)](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2)